# Mysql Update na média de alunos

Tags: mysql, tupla

oi, bom , tenho um bd com vários alunos inseridos, e no exercício preciso tirar a média deles e inserir numa nova coluna.
mas quando eu faço um select pra testar antes de realizar o update o meu comando ele junta todas as notas de todos os alunos e tira uma média disso.
como eu faço para tirar a média de aluno por aluno ?
meu código : select (avg(p1)+avg(p2))  from notas;
 eu nem estou sabendo como pesquisar o meu problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Update notas set media = ((p1+p2)/2)  , talvez falte um round conforme o type  da coluna. Uma outra solução pode ser criar uma coluna virtual

Comment: Então você colocou uma imagem do seu código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Entenda os motivos [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça dessa forma aqui, assim dará certo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caso queira deixar mais organizado, é só fazer asism

SELECT * , ((n1+n2)/2) AS 'Media' FROM NOTAS

Comment: Gustavo, prefira código em texto do que em imagem. Explicação do porquê está [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: poxa assim eu consigo kkk , mas queria usar o avg, será que não é possível ?
porem obrigado mesmo assim :3